# AWS EC2 linux + PHP + ODBC + Remote MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-ec2, odbc, freetds

I'm developing a web application with an AWS EC2 server (using php) to access a MS SQL Server database.

After a long search for solutions, I found this solution to use an ODBC driver. Fine, the development went well and I have no problems to connect to database or persist data.

But when I deployed my application, any action returns this error:

> ERRO: IM001: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver does not support this
>   function

I really tried all that I know and couldn't resolve this.

My EC2 configuration is:

> yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel freetds freetds-devel

And my odbc/freetds conf files are:

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[TDS_NAME]
      Description = decription
      Driver = TDS_NAME
      Database = MY_DB
      Servername = TDS_NAME
      UID = VIPS
      Port = 1433
      TDS_Version= 7.3
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[TDS_NAME]
      Description = TDS Connection
      Driver64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
      Setup64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
      FileUsage = 1
      UsageCount = 1
[ODBC]
      Trace = yes
      TraceFile /tmp/odbc.log
```

**/etc/freetds.conf**

```
[TDS_NAME]
      host = MY_HOST
      port = MY_PORT
      tds version = 7.3
```

I run my queries using odbc_execute() or odbc_exec() and the error happens when my consult has some parameter. I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't my configuration files because I can connect successfully to the server and run a simple "SELECT * FROM table" and connect using isql running any query goes well.

Anyone can help me?

OBS: PHP RUNNING VERSION - PHP 5.6.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- What version of FreeTDS are you running?
- What version of SQL Server are you running?

You need this to properly pick the correct TDS version. You're configured to use TDS 7.3, which would require FreeTDS 0.95 and SQL Server 2008. If you're just doing basic stuff, perhaps consider changing your TDS Version to 7.2 or 7.1?

Here's a handy chart of what features are supported by which TDS version in FreeTDS:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't have so much luck :( I tried to upgrade my freeTDS version (to 0.95) and downgrade my TDS version. But the same error appears. By the way, is there any repository to freeTDS 0.95? I did download and installed by the tar.gz. I don't know if was installed all right because the installation didn't create a symbolic link to tsql, I needed do this by myself...

Comment: And ah, it was a earlier version of freeTDS that was running, I installed using 'yum install freetds' and got this version. My SQL Server is 2008.

Comment: Now I got it! Besides upgrade my freeTDS to 0.95 I've had to remove all params from my queries, I don't know if is the better solution but it works! Thanks :)

Comment: Good work! Sorry I didn't see this earlier. Hopefully that gets you over the hump from here.